# Forms Recognizer 408 request time-out with custom\train API call

Tags: c#, request, azure-cognitive-services, timeoutexception

Using Forms Recognizer to Train a model with 6 sample forms and API call times out with 408.

Followed documentation.  Uploaded sample forms to blob storage and put valid (active) SAS key in {"source":""} json object in request body.

```
string requestBody = "{ \"source\": \"" + "<valid_SAS_URL>" + "\"}";
var content = new StringContent(requestBody);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
```

Should have received a success json string but instead a 408 timeout.  No other info is available about why this might have happened.  No log entries on the Azure side that I could find.

Comment: Checking to see if Microsoft might have changed their endpoint.

Comment: Can you share the Uri and sample data that you are trying?

Comment: Turns out the process I was requesting did indeed take too long and will need to reduce the size of my dataset or increase the timeout value if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the Input requirements for the Form Recognizer.
[image]